# Helpers de Laravel en og:title

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

preparando la plantilla de mi web estoy haciendo esto:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('ogTitle')" />
```

Luego en cada archivo de cada vista estoy haciendo esto:

```
@section('ogTitle', '{{ $blog->titulo }}')
```

Pero parece que el helper de laravel no lo comprende, por que viendo el código fuente de la página sale:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="&lt;?php echo e($blog-&gt;titulo); ?&gt;" />
```

Sabeis como tengo que hacerlo para que entienda el helper?? También he probado con `@php echo %blg->titulo @endphp` pero sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Probaste `@section('ogTitle', $blog->titulo)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno después de buscar y buscar consegui esta opción:

```
@section('ogTitle') pagina | {{ $blog->titulo }} @stop
```

Simplemente añadiendo `@stop` al final de cada `@section`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estas en la linea de @section es como si estuvieras en "php", no necesitas "renderear" el valor de la variable bajo los dobles llaves `{{`, pasa tu valor directo

```
@section('ogTitle', $blog->titulo)
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenid@ , ya probe de esta forma sin éxito. Mira mi respuesta que así de este modo si funciona.

Comment: Yo actualmente lo tengo funcionando asi como te lo sugeri, a la mejor es la version del Laravel, igual me da gusto que ya este funcionando!!!